# Android Composable relative position to parent (X,Y)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Canvas` composable I created that allows me to drag and scale a child composable within the boundaries of the parent (the `Canvas`).

I need to know what is the position of the child composable relative to its parent (the `Canvas`) at any given time while being dragged or scaled.

```
GridCanvas(
    ratio = canvasRatio,
) { gridWidth, gridHeight ->

    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    RenderedImage(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                    val futureScale = scale * zoom

                    if (futureScale in MIN_SCALE_FACTOR..MAX_SCALE_FACTOR) {
                        scale = futureScale
                    }

                    offsetX += pan.x
                    offsetY += pan.y
                }
            }
            .graphicsLayer {
                this.scaleX = scale
                this.scaleY = scale
                this.translationX = offsetX
                this.translationY = offsetY
            },
        imageUri = someUri,
    )
}
```

How to get the `X` and `Y` position of the child `RenderedImage` relative to its parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it from `Modifier.onGloballyPosition{ it.positionInParent()}` and position in root and in window too if needed.This one returns your Composable position in parent.

Unlike `onTouchEvent` in View, `pointerInputChange` events start from (0,0), onTouchEvents use global position of View in window. When you are at top corner of your Composable Offset that is returned is (0,0).

If you want to get touch position inside your Composable you can use first param which is `centroid`, it returns the **center of pointers**. if you have one pointer down, it's pointer's touch position, when you have 2, 3, or more it's center of pointers that are down relative to start of your Composble. If you add the initial position of your Composable in parent you can get that either.

Let's say you have a composable like the one below

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp).background(Color.Red))
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
        MyComposable()
    }
}
```

And MyComposable which you need coordinates

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {


    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(300.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            val positionInParent: Offset = it.positionInParent()
            val positionInRoot: Offset = it.positionInRoot()
            val positionInWindow: Offset = it.positionInWindow()
            text =
                "positionInParent: $positionInParent\n" +
                        "positionInRoot: $positionInRoot\n" +
                        "positionInWindow: $positionInWindow"
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My intention was to know the position while the child composable is being dragged or scaled. `onGloballyPositioned` will be just called once. I have updated my question to make it more clear though! :)

Comment: @TareKKhoury `onGloballyPositioned`actually gets called many times your Composable gets into composition but i got what you mean, and updated my answer. If you want the position of touch you can use first paremeter of `onGesture: (centroid: Offset, pan: Offset, zoom: Float, rotation: Float) -> Unit`. If you have only single pointer down this one returns the position of that pointer, when you have multiple it returns the center of touch. But touch system in Composable starts from 0 that's why i ask if you need position in parent or not. On top left with one pointer you will get 0,0 as offset.

Comment: If centroid is not enough, you always need the touch position of first pointer, you can add another `pointerInput(Unit)` and get position of touch from this one while using `detectTransformgestures` for zoom, rotation or translation. You can have multiple `Modifier.pointerInput(Unit)` each with different roles and one without not effecting other based on how you consume `pointerInputChange`s.